# Flask REST: TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, rest, flask, openshift

Hey I am having an issue with a Flask REST endpoint, that has an optional argument. I have the exact same code in other places and it works so I am at a loss here.

Here is the code for the Resource:

```
@api.route(
    "/get_sick_calls/<string:start_date>/<string:end_date>/",
    "/get_sick_calls/<string:start_date>/<string:end_date>/<int:num_sick_calls>",
    defaults={'num_sick_calls': 3}
)
class GetSickCalls(Resource):

    ##method_decorators = [authenticate]

    @api.doc(
        responses={
            201: "OK",
            401: INVALID_DATE_MSG,
            402: "DATE_RANGE_INVALID",
        },
        params={
            "start_date": "ISO 8601 Date String: YYYY-mm-dd",
            "end_date": "ISO 8601 Date String: YYYY-mm-dd",
            "num_sick_calls": "Minium number of sick calls, default is 3",
        },
    )
    # @authenticate
    def get(self, start_date: str, end_date: str, num_sick_calls: int):
        # validate date inputs
```

Whenever I access either route I get a 500 Internal Server Error: `TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'num_sick_calls'`

I have tried changing `num_sick_calls` to `*args, **kwargs` but same thing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I apologize, there was nothing wrong with that code, I did not realize that there was another get method below that one overwriting the first (not sure why I appoved that PR...)